# Wrong Password Is Getting Assigned To DB User

Tags: oracle

I have written below SQL script to drop and recreate user and tablespace for it in Oracle 11g DB.

Please have a look.

```
Alter user DEMO account lock; 
drop user DEMO cascade; 
alter tablespace DEMO offline; 
drop tablespace DEMO including contents and datafiles; 

CREATE TABLESPACE DEMO DATAFILE 
'E:\Oracle\oradata\sora161\DEMO-1.dbf' SIZE 5M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1024M, 
'E:\Oracle\oradata\sora161\DEMO-2.dbf' SIZE 5M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1024M, 
'E:\Oracle\oradata\sora161\DEMO-3.dbf' SIZE 5M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1024M; 

CREATE USER DEMO 
IDENTIFIED BY "p2pcomdaily" 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE DEMO 
QUOTA unlimited ON DEMO 
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP 
PROFILE DEFAULT; 
GRANT CONNECT,DBA,ABC_DBO to DEMO;
```

Here in above script everything is working fine except one thing and that is wrong password is getting assigned to user while creation. As you can see in above script I have to set password as p2pcomdaily but its getting set as something else.

Can someone please help me to understand where I am wrong here?

Comment: You aren't showing what happens when you try to connect as that user and with that password. What error do you get? Are you sure you're trying to connect to the instance the account was created in - can you `connect demo/p2pcomdaily` in the same session where you create the user?

Comment: Hi, I can see in Oracle Enterprise Manager cosole that some 8 characters password is getting assigned. Whereas my p2pcomdaily password is of 11 characters.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing that - and do you see an actual plain-text password (which seems rather unlikely), or eight stars/bullets that are just representing a hidden password and have nothing to do with its actual setting or length? Have you tried actually connecting with those credentials?

Comment: Ohh I am really very sorry Alex. I was just guessing the password is wrong by looking at number of characters (stars) showing in Oracle Enterprise Manager console. But with that wrong guess I was not trying to actual logging into DB. As you suggested I tried and I got logged in successfully with my password set in script.. Thanks a lot Alex. And really very sorry for such fullish guess..

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem.

Actually there was no problem with Password or script.

It was Oracle enterprise Manager Console showing wrong number of characters for user where I used to check for correct password. Even if Oracle Enterprise Manager console is showing 8 characters password instead of my 11 characters password there was no problem with password.

I am able to login with my p2pcomdaily password which I am setting in my script.

Thanks Alex for your valuable help.

Thanks, 
Vinayak

Comment: It's not showing the *wrong* number; it shows an arbitrary number so that it doesn't reveal anything about the actual password. If it showed 11 stars/bullets then it would potentially make it easier to crack; or looking at it the other way an attacker would be able to search for accounts with shorter passwords to  target.